# Seeking approval from coauthors for poster after they have approved the abstract

Tags: conference, authorship, poster, abstract

I submitted an abstract to a conference about a month ago, with a clear idea that it will be presented either in the form of an oral presentation or as a poster presentation should it be accepted. Prior to submitting, I sent all coauthors an email seeking for approval for the abstract submission.

Now that the abstract has been accepted, I need to further submit a poster which I will present at the conference. Do I need to email all the coauthors again to seek approval for the poster? Or is the approval implied when they responded favourably to my abstract submission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I need to email all the coauthors again to seek approval for the poster? Or is the approval implied when they responded favourably to my abstract submission?

Yes, of course. Their names will be on it, so they need to see it. I think the importance of getting feedback on visual materials is easily double that of written material, given all the degrees of freedom.

Just a side note, I find your usage of "approval" a bit odd. You should be asking your co-authors for feedback and suggestions for improvement, and collaboratively building your abstract/poster/paper. Of course, I don't know the role they had, but if someone sent me "an abstract for my approval," I would feel a bit off-put and uncomfortable saying "no" and sending my suggestions.